# Favorskii rearrangment

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Why does the alkoxide anion dont act as a nucleophile in the fevorskii rearrangement?
It can displace halide as halide is alpha to carbonyl and carbonyl decreses the energy of c-halide lumo

Comment: It can but because intremolecule reactions are much faster then intermolecular reactions you get mostly the rearrangement product.

Comment: SN2 reactions on secondary alkyl halides is not that fast.